# how to read formulas with xlrd

Tags: python, excel, xlrd

I am trying to do a parser, that reads several excel files. I need values usually at the bottom of a row where you find a sum of all upper elements. So the cell value is actually "=sum()" or "A5*0.5" lets say... To a user that opens this file with excel it appears like  a number, which is fine. But if I try to read this value with ws.cell(x, y).value I do not get anything.

So my question is how to read this kind of fields with xlrd, if it is possible to read it like ws.cell(x, y).value or something similar?

thanks

Comment: This link should provide you the guidelines: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4690423/get-formula-from-excel-cell-with-python-xlrd

Answer (score 0):

As per the link for your question,I have posted above, the author of xlrd says, 'The work is 'in-progress' but is not likely to be available soon as the focus of xlrd lies elsewhere". By this, I assume that there is nothing much you can do about it. Note: this is based on author's comment on Jan, 2011.

Comment: afaicr excel saves the current value along with the formula so you should be able to get the value even if you cant evaluate the formula

Comment: for reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4690423/get-formula-from-excel-cell-with-python-xlrd