# Can Python recognize a formula from Excel cell?

Tags: python, excel, formula

Can Python recognize formula from Excel cell and ignore processing the cell which has formulas?

Comment: Seeing as how formulas always start with an equals sign, that shouldn't be too hard.

Comment: Visually, array formulas start with { so take care if you adopt SBI's approach.

Comment: Are you using a library such as Apache POI to read the excel file into Python's memory? This library will tell you the data type of a cell (numeric, string, equation, error)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but instead of reinventing the wheel. I would use one of these [libraries](http://www.python-excel.org/).
They seem to provide what you need and a Tutorial is also available.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [answer provided by the author of xlrd in Jan 2011](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4690423/get-formula-from-excel-cell-with-python-xlrd), [xlrd](http://www.python-excel.org/) does not currently provide access to Excel formulas.  As I'm currently trying to do this, I'm inclined to believe that this is still the case - I'm working with version 0.9.2 which according to [github](https://github.com/python-excel/xlrd/releases) is the latest. I've just noticed there is [xlrd1 on PyPI](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/xlrd1/1.0.0), but as the two limitations listed are

- There is no support for files in the Microsoft Excel 2007/2010 format
- One cannot extract formulas from the input file

this offers no joy either.

Although my search is hardly exhaustive (I'm in a hurry), I'm of the opinion that the only sure way of accessing formulas in Python is to access the underlying COM object via [Mark Hammond's pywin32](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pywin32).  Fairly obviously you will need Excel installed, so this will limit the availability of this solution away from Windows.  I'm currently using the [Python Excels website](http://pythonexcels.com/python-excel-mini-cookbook/) for a bit of inspiration.  I'm afraid that I don't have any reliable or coherent code as yet - my answer is posted mainly to warn that xlrd is sadly not yet the answer to grabbing Excel formulas via Python.

===
Tue 18.Mar.2014
BTW as I am moderately new to stackoverflow and currently lack the ability to comment or recommend, I would add that this answer was added specifically in light of the inadequacy of the previous answer to the question "can Python recognize a formula from an Excel cell?"  which xlrd for all its merits does not.  The main reason I posted an incompletely researched answer was to warn other users of a false positive which, for all its merits, xlrd is in this instance.

I'm currently engaged in many tasks, one of which involves this question.  If I find an approach which "does" rather than one which "might" answer this question, other than the approach I have given, I will amend my answer.

Comment: You may wish to check out [OpenPyXL](http://pythonhosted.org/openpyxl/) if dealing with Excel 2007 onwards. I'm not 100% sure but that might offer formula support.