# Find if a value exists in a column in Excel using python

Tags: python, excel, arcpy

I have an Excel file with one worksheet that has sediment collection data. I am running a long Python script.

In the worksheet is a column titled “CollectionYear.” Say I want the year 2010. If the year 2010 exists in the “CollectionYear” column, I want the rest of the script to run, if not then I want the script to stop.

This seems like an easy enough task but for the life of me I cannot figure it out nor find any examples.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What file format is the file in?

Comment: What do you have so far?

Comment: Reading Excel-files is kind of weird. Think about exporting the data to csv-fileformat and use [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#io-read-csv-table) to analyse it.

Comment: What libraries are you currently using? [xlrd](http://www.lexicon.net/sjmachin/xlrd.html) may be able to help. Please show some code and where the problem is.

Answer (score 1):

I use xlrd all the time and it works great for me. Something like this might be helpful

```
from xlrd import open_workbook

def main():
    book = open_workbook('example.xlsx')
    sheet = book.sheet_by_index(0)
    collection_year_col = 2 #Just an example
    test_year = 2010
    for row in range(sheet.nrows):
        if sheet.cell(row,collection_year_col).value == test_year:
            runCode()

def runCode():
    #your code
```

I hope this points you in the right direction. More help could be given if the details of your problem were known.

Comment: You can also find more xlrd documentation at http://www.lexicon.net/sjmachin/xlrd.html

Comment: Hi, I tried this with the following code and it gives no error but never runs the `runcode()`. Can you provide some guidance on how to make it work? My value of interest (=2011) is in cell C7 of my excel file.

Comment: My code: `def main():
book = open_workbook('/dir/file.xlsx', index_col=0)
    sheet = 'Sheet1'
    collection_year_col = 'Unnamed: 2' 
    test_year = 2011
    for row in range(nrows=7):
        if sheet.cell(row,collection_year_col).value == test_year:
            runCode()
            
def runCode():
    print("worked!")`

Comment: So it has been a few years. But if you are still struggling I might suggest printing out the type of the value of `sheet.cell(row,collection_year_col).value` you might be comparing a string to an int.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I learned from tackling a needle-in-a-haystack problem for a gigantic pile of `.xls` files.  There are some things `xlrd` and friends can't ([or won't](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4695498/5065796)) do, such as getting the formula of a cell.  For that, you'll need to use the Microsoft [Component Object Model (COM)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/com/com-objects-and-interfaces)<sup>1</sup>.

I recommend you find yourself a copy of *Python Programming on Win32* by Mark Hammond.  It's still useful 20 years later.  *Python Programming on Win32* covers the basics of the COM and how to access it using the [`pywin32`](https://github.com/mhammond/pywin32) library (also from Mark Hammond).

In a nutshell, you can think of the COM as an API between a server (say, Excel) and a client (such as a Python script)<sup>2</sup>.

```py
import win32com.client

# Connect to Excel server
xl = win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
```

The COM API is [reasonably well documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/overview/).  Once you get used to the terminology, things become straight-forward albeit tedious.  For example, an Excel file is technically a "Workbook".  The "Workbooks" COM object has [the Open method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbooks.open) which provides a handle for Python to interact with the "Workbook". (Did you notice the different *'s'* endings on those?)

```py
import win32com.client

# Connect to Excel server
xl = win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")

myfile = r'C:\temp\myworkbook.xls'
wb = xl.Workbooks.Open(Filename=myfile)
```

A "Workbook" contains a "Sheet", accessed here through the "Sheets" COM object:

```py
import win32com.client

# Connect to Excel server
xl = win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")

myfile = r'C:\temp\myworkbook.xls'
wb = xl.Workbooks.Open(Filename=myfile)
sht1 = wb.Sheets.Item(1)
```

Finally, the '[Cells](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.cells)' property of a worksheet "returns a Range object that represents all the cells on the worksheet".  The Range object then has a [Find](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.find) method which will search within the range.  The *LookIn* parameter allows for searching cell values, formulas, and comments.

```py
import win32com.client

# Connect to Excel server
xl = win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")

myfile = r'C:\temp\myworkbook.xls'
wb = xl.Workbooks.Open(Filename=myfile)
sht1 = wb.Sheets.Item(1)
match = sht1.Cells.Find('search string')
```

The result of *Find* is a Range object which has many useful [properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range(object)#properties), like *Formula*, *GetAddress*, *Value*, and *Text*.  You'll also find, as with anything Microsoft, that it's good enough for government work.

Finally, don't forget to close the workbook and to quit Excel!

```py
import win32com.client

# Connect to Excel server
xl = win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")

myfile = r'C:\temp\myworkbook.xls'
wb = xl.Workbooks.Open(Filename=myfile)
sht1 = wb.Sheets.Item(1)
match = sht1.Cells.Find('search string')

print(match.Formula)

wb.Close(SaveChanges=False)
xl.Quit()
```

You can extend these ideas with [`Sheets.Item`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.sheets.item) and [`Sheets.Count`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.sheets.count) and iterate over all sheets in a workbook (or all workbooks in a directory).  You can have lots of fun!

The headaches you may encounter include VBA macros and embedded objects, as well as the various different alerts each can produce.  Performance is also an issue.  The following silence notifications and can dramatically improve performance:

**Application**

- [xl.DisplayAlerts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.displayalerts) (False)
- [xl.AutomationSecurity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.automationsecurity) (msoAutomationSecurityForceDisable)
- [xl.Interactive](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.interactive) (False)
- [xl.PrintCommunication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.printcommunication) (False)
- [xl.ScreenUpdating](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.screenupdating) (False)
- [xl.StatusBar](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.statusbar) (False)

**Workbook**

- [wb.DoNotPromptForConvert](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.donotpromptforconvert) (True)
- [wb.EnableAutoRecover](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.enableautorecover) (False)
- [wb.KeepChangeHistory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.keepchangehistory) (False)

Another potential issue is [late/early binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/office-developer/binding-type-available-to-automation-clients).  Basically, does Python have information about the COM object?  This affects things like introspection and how COM objects are referenced.  The `win32com.client` package uses late-bound automation by default.

With late-bound automation, Python doesn't know much about the COM object:

```py
>> import win32com.client
>> xl = win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
>> xl
<COMObject Excel.Application>
>> len(dir(xl))
55
```

With early-bound automation, Python has full knowledge of the object:

```py
>> import win32com.client
>> xl = win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
>> xl
<win32com.gen_py.Microsoft Excel 16.0 Object Library._Application instance at 0x2583562290680>
>> len(dir(xl))
125
```

To enable early binding, you must run `makepy.py` which is included with `pywin32`.  Running `makepy.py` will prompt for the library to bind with.

```sh
(venv) c:\temp\venv\Lib\site-packages\win32com\client>python makepy.py
python makepy.py
```

[image]

The process creates a Python file (in `Temp\`) which maps the methods and properties of the COM object.

```sh
(venv) c:\temp\venv\Lib\site-packages\win32com\client>python makepy.py
python makepy.py
Generating to C:\Users\Lorem\AppData\Local\Temp\gen_py\3.6\00020813-0000-0000-C000-000000000046x0x1x9.py
Building definitions from type library...
Generating...
Importing module
```

Early binding also provides access to COM constants, such as [`msoAutomationSecurityForceDisable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/office.msoautomationsecurity) and [`xlAscending`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xlsortorder) and is case-sensitive (whereas late-binding is not).

That should be enough info to implement a Python-to-Excel library (like [`xlwings`](https://github.com/xlwings/xlwings/tree/master/xlwings)), overkill notwithstanding.

---

<sup>1</sup> Actually, `xlwings` works by utilizing the COM though `pywin32`.  Here's to one less dependency!

<sup>2</sup> This example uses `win32com.client.Dispatch` which requires processing happen through a single Excel instance.  Use `win32com.client.DispatchEx` to create separate instances of Excel.

Comment: can you show how to use parameter `LookAt:=xlWhole,`?
google say use `LookAt=Excel.constants.xlWhole` but it doesn't work (

Answer (score 0):

Try using [`xlwings`](http://xlwings.org/quickstart/) library to interface with Excel from python

example from their docs:

```
from xlwings import Workbook, Sheet, Range, Chart
wb = Workbook()  # Creates a connection with a new workbook
Range('A1').value = 'Foo 1'
Range('A1').value
>>> 'Foo 1'
Range('A1').value = [['Foo 1', 'Foo 2', 'Foo 3'], [10.0, 20.0, 30.0]]
```