# how to find a specific value form a huge piile of excel files?

Tags: python, excel

I want to find a specific value form an excel files (like a number of "543.45") from a huge pile of excel files (which is around 800 files) which is in a folder. How can i do that?

Comment: Please give more details and what you have done so far

Comment: Welcome to SO. I am afraid, SO is not a free coding service. Please show [your code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and describe why it didn't give the expected output. I suggest to edit your question, after [reading the guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `xlrd` module to do things with Excel files. I have never used xlrd before, however spent the last half hour to understand enough to make this code:

```
import xlrd
import os
import time
directory = input("Enter the folder with Excel files: ")
number = input("What number would you like to find? ")
number = float(number)
os.chdir(directory)
for filename in os.listdir(directory): # Iterates through each file
    if filename.endswith(".xlsx") or filename.endswith("xlsm"):
        book = xlrd.open_workbook(filename)
        sheet = book.sheet_by_index(0)
        for row in range(sheet.nrows): # Iterates through each row
            for column in range(sheet.ncols): # Iterates through each column
                currentcell = sheet.cell_value(row, column) # Gets the value for the row and column it is currently on
                try:
                    currentcell = float(currentcell)
                except ValueError: # In case the cell contains a string.
                    pass
                if currentcell == number:
                    print("Found the value {} in the file {} at {}:{} (col:row)".format(number, filename, column, row))
```

Note that you will have to close any excel file you are trying to check.

It iterates through every file, through every row and every column to check if the number is equal to the specified number, so it is not that efficient, however it works. It will return the where the number was found in which file.

Links I used:

- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p0DNcTnreuY
- [Find if a value exists in a column in Excel using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30678721/find-if-a-value-exists-in-a-column-in-excel-using-python)