# How to get the value that a formula in excel returns using Pandas?

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have an excel workbook with multiple sheets and I am using pandas to access it. The first sheet is the one that contains formulas that access the rest of the sheets and perform some calculations. When I access the first sheet and print the data frame, the columns that uses formulas are printed as Nan. How can I get the value instead of Nan?

```
import numpy as np 
import pandas as pd 

refitemPath = ".\\170310-test.xlsx"

xlsxFile = pd.ExcelFile(refitemPath)
df = pd.read_excel(xlsxFile, 'Result')
print(df)
```

Here is an example result
[image]

and the actual values

[image]

Comment: Sorry, I can't get this to replicate. Can you possible provide a better example? I have a .xlsx with two sheets, one of which refers to another sheet with a formula, and it reads in values instead of NaNs just fine. Perhaps try specifying a dtype for the relevant column? https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_excel.html

Comment: If it's not too much of a hassle, can you just create another spreadsheet and paste from the original file but only keep the value?

Comment: @Dylan My formula is, =IF(ROUNDDOWN(VLOOKUP(J4,'Inventory'!$A:$Z,6)/3,0)-4>0,ROUNDDOWN(VLOOKUP(J4,'Inventory'!$A:$Z,6)/3,0)-4,0), not sure if this helps. I will try specifying a dtype.

Comment: @XiaoyuLu I am trying to automate the entire process, I think creating a new spreadsheet will not help because I would still need the results from the formula

Comment: @Dylan I try using dtype, and converters. Had no luck.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42180446/1675954  a regex solution

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41730454/1675954 a possible alternative solution

Comment: @RachelGallen The second link, I did as Colton T suggested, save the file first. That worked, it displayed the numbers.

Comment: @paul brilliant. Success! Always good to have a happy ending :)

Comment: @RachelGallen Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [pandas read excel values not formulas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41722374/pandas-read-excel-values-not-formulas)