# Can I write a python function to automate a data download process with excel?

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel, automation

I am currently using Excel to request data from MorningStar. What I do is to enter a function in the first cell (A1) and press enter and Excel will return the data. I will then have to open a new sheet or file and  enter the function with a new value for the parameter (day) in the first cell to get a new dataset. I have thousands of value for that parameter and thinking about manually changing it gives me a nightmare. I am just wondering if Python can write a function that iterates through the list of that parameter (days), go to excel and execute the command for each day and save to a file?

Comment: Does this need to be done with excel? This question could help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4690423/get-formula-from-excel-cell-with-python-xlrd
However, it may be simpler to have python get the data and save it to file and cut excel out of the middle.

Comment: @KyleAlm Ideally, I would not want to open excel as it is slow. However, I think i have to open excel because I need to download data from an add-in. I have a further question related to this issue, can you please have a look?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61788229/python-how-to-start-excell-add-in-request-data-and-save

Answer (score 0):

Of course- anything is possible with Python due to its awesomeness! The code below loops over a list of dates, writes out the date by using the `Date` function in Excel (substitute your own function) and saves off the file with a different name.

Whether it works with your specific function and issues related to timing (e.g., the data might take some time to download etc) is something you will have to test on your own.

```
import datetime as dt
import openpyxl

workbook_name = 'example.xlsx'
output_file_name = 'example_output'

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(workbook_name)
sheet = wb['Sheet1']

all_dates = [dt.date(2020, 1, 1), dt.date(2020, 1, 2)]

for a_date in all_dates:
    sheet['A1'].value = f'=Date({a_date.year}, {a_date.month}, {a_date.day})'

    wb.save(f'{output_file_name}_{a_date.strftime("%Y_%m_%d")}.xlsx')

wb.close()
```

Comment: Thanks. I am aware of this. However, what I would like to achieve is to let Excel open this file. The moment the file is open, the function in cell A1 will be executed,  and returns data. I then would like to close the date and go on the next file. If I understand your code correctly, it just write the fuction to excel without opening the file and executing the code

Comment: since you said anything is possible with python, do you mind having a look at my question here 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61788229/python-how-to-start-excell-add-in-request-data-and-save