# Python: how to start Excell add-in, request data, and save?

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel

I have an excel add-in (morningstar) that allows me to request and download data by entering a function with some parameters in cell A1. I have a thousand values of parameters that I need to get the data for so I would want to automate this process. I can (sort of) do that with VBA but it takes forever, and crashes many times. I would like to do this in Python. The logic which I am doing in VBA is as follows:

1. Open the xlsx file (workbook)
2. Refresh Excel so to make sure the Add-in is loaded and data is downloaded
3. Loop through sheets and save as csv files

I tried opening the excel file with python using the subprocess package. But I cannot make it until the data is downloaded. I attached 2 photos of the download process: (i)when the function in cell A1 is executed, the cell display "Processing..." . It would take a few seconds to a few minutes depending on the size of the data. when done, the data looks like in the second photo.
[image: when the function in cell A1 is executed, the cell display "Processing..."]
[image: Output data]

So my questions are:

1. How to ask python to start excel and load the add-in?
2. Execute the fuction in cell A1, or at least refresh excel to make sure the function runs.
3. Instead of asking python to wait for an exact time, how do I ask python to check if the data is downloaded?

Ideally, (I think) doing this without opening excel would save a lot of time, but not a major issue.

Comment: Taking excel out of the picture would be ideal. Take a look at the Morningstar API collection - https://developer.morningstar.com/apis.

Comment: yeah i saw that. it would not work because what I am requesting is a special data for which morningstar does not allow python API yet